# How do I select files 1-88

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a files in the directory named OIS001_OD_EYE_MIC.png - OIS176_OD_EYE_MIC.png

Extract numbers 1-99 is easy as show by this regex.
I want 1-88 to divide the directory in half.

Why? So I can have two even sets of files to compress

```
ls | sed  -n '/^[A-Z]*0[0-9][0-9].*EYE_MIC.png/p'
```

Here is my attempt of getting 0-99. Can you help me get 1-88 and perhaps 89-176?

Comment: Should be easier to select an interval with other things than regex

Comment: Really? Do you have a link to do that? sed is one big program. I need to extract certain file from my directory to send. I do not mind if there is other utilies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regexes you have to think about how the strings of certain number ranges look (you can't just match specific number ranges directly). 1-88:

```
/^[A-Z]*(00[1-9]|0[1-7][0-9]|08[0-8]).*EYE_MIC.png/
```

For 88 - 176:

```
/^[A-Z]*(089|09[0-9]|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6]).*EYE_MIC.png/
```

[Here are some more examples.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. I am a newbie with regex and I understand it is powerful, but do not understand it limitations

Answer (score 5):

You can use a range: `{start..end}` like this:

```
echo OIS00{0..88}_OD_EYE_MIC.png
```

will expand to

```
OIS000_OD_EYE_MIC.png OIS001_OD_EYE_MIC.png [...] OIS0087_OD_EYE_MIC.png OIS0088_OD_EYE_MIC.png
```

Look for *[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)* in bash's man page

Answer (score 4):

With a new-enough bash:

```
ls OIS0{01..88}_OD_EYE_MIC.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piped parallel alternative:

```
ls -v | columns --by-columns -c2 | tr -s ' '   \
| tee >(cut -d' ' -f1 | tar cf part1.tar -T -) \
      >(cut -d' ' -f2 | tar cf part2.tar -T -) > /dev/null
```

This method needs more work if the files have whitespace in their names.

The idea is to columnate the file-list and use `tee` to multiplex it into separate compression processes.

The `columns` program comes with the `autogen` package (at least in Debian).

Comment: I make my files without whitespace, but I do appreciate the example. Thank You